# Pycharm and library root removal

Tags: dependencies, pycharm

[image]

I cannot remove **D:** as a library root and Pycharm keeps indexing forever. Any suggestions?

**Edit:** D: is not in any path variable

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure `D:\` is not added to interpreter paths in **Settings | Project ... | Project Interpreter | Show All | Interepter Paths**:

[image]